# Best way to separate data into 3 classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I have a numpy array as

```
[['6.5' '3.2' '5.1' '2.0' 'Iris-virginica'] 
['6.1' '2.8' '4.0' '1.3' 'Iris-versicolor'] 
['4.6' '3.2' '1.4' '0.2' 'Iris-setosa']
['6.0' '2.2' '4.0' '1.0' 'Iris-versicolor']
['4.7' '3.2' '1.3' '0.2' 'Iris-setosa']
['6.7' '3.1' '5.6' '2.4' 'Iris-virginica']]
```

What would be the fastest way to separate this data into 3 separate numpy arrays based on the label '`Iris-virginica'`, `'Iris-setosa'` and `'Iris-virginica'` so that

`Iris-virginica`array contains only 
`[['6.5' '3.2' '5.1' '2.0']['6.7' '3.1' '5.6' '2.4']]`

`Iris-setosa`array contains only `[['4.6' '3.2' '1.4' '0.2'] ['4.7' '3.2' '1.3' '0.2']]`

`Iris-versicolor`array contains only `[['6.1' '2.8' '4.0' '1.3']['6.0' '2.2' '4.0' '1.0']]`

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You have have duplicate "classes" of each with different values. Also how do you want the covariances calculating? With respect to every other "class"?

Comment: A fellow traveller in the CoDA course?

Comment: @ Ffisegydd: I changed the question.

Comment: FWIW this would be much simpler using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org); you basically want `groupby` + `mean` IIUC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `numpy` and list `comprehension`,

```
import numpy as np

data = [['6.5', '3.2', '5.1', '2.0', 'Iris-virginica'],
['6.1', '2.8', '4.0', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor'] ,
['4.6', '3.2', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
['6.0', '2.2', '4.0', '1.0', 'Iris-versicolor'],
['4.7', '3.2', '1.3', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
['6.7', '3.1', '5.6', '2.4', 'Iris-virginica']]

filtered = [map(float, item[:4]) for item in data if item[4] == 'Iris-virginica']
print 'mean', np.mean(filtered, axis=0)
print 'var ', np.var(filtered, axis=0)
```

where `item[4] == 'Iris-virginica'` filters what you want, and `map(float, item[:3])` is for `str` to `float`, then `np.mean(..., axis=0)` is to get `mean` of the filtered data.

The output is

```
mean [ 6.6   3.15  5.35]
var  [ 0.01    0.0025  0.0625]
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here is `numpy` only version, but this seems like slower than the above.

```
data = np.array(data)
filtered = data[data[:, 4] == 'Iris-virginica'][:, :3].astype(np.float)
print 'mean', np.mean(filtered, axis=0)
print 'var ', np.var(filtered, axis=0)
```

The `timeit` result is

```
In [5]: %timeit filtered = [map(float, item[:4]) for item in data if item[4] == 'Iris-virginica']
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.93 µs per loop

In [6]: data = np.array(data)

In [7]: timeit data[data[:, 4] == 'Iris-virginica'][:, :4].astype(np.float)
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed my question slightly

Comment: Minor: I think you want `[:4]`, not `[:3]`, or you're skipping a column of data.