# How do I load data from a text file and then put them in a dictionary?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, file-io

I have a data file where the first 4 csv's are floats, and the last value
is a string that represents a label for that row

```
.5, .3, .2, .1, FAA
.2., .3, .5., .2, FXX
.5., .3, .2 , .9, FXX
.3, .3, .9, .3, FCA
```

I want to load the file into a numpy array that organizes them by
classes, so the output would be something like:

```
FAA: [[.5, .3, .2, .1]]
FXX: [[.2., .3, .5., .2],
      [.5., .3, .2 , .9]]
FCA: [.3, .3, .9, .3]
```

It's very similar to this, but I could not get this to work in my own code:
[Best way to separate data into 3 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544707/best-way-to-separate-data-into-3-classes)

This code works, but I can't figure out how to not add the label inside of each datapoint:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=('length', 'width', 'distance', 'strength', 'label'))

separated = {}
for i in range(len(data)):
    vector = data[i]
    if (vector[-1] not in separated):
        separated[vector[-1]] = []
    separated[vector[-1]].append(vector)
for i in range(len(separated)):
               print separated
               print '\n'
```

Once I get that the way I want it, I will compute the mean and co variance matrix from there.

EDIT: When I run the code from the linked page, I get the following error:

```
filtered = [map(float, item[:4]) for item in data if item[4] == 'Iris-virginica']
IndexError: invalid index
```

How is the index invalid?

Comment: Please do not post to external code repositories and do not ask questions about externally posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas for that

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt',
                 delimiter=', ',
                 names=['length', 'width', 'distance', 'strength', 'label'])

output = {}
for label in ['FAA', 'FXX', 'FCA']:
    output[label] = df[df['label'] == label].copy().drop('label', 1).as_matrix()
```

Comment: Hm. Is there a way to do it without using pandas?

Comment: @cparks10 If you use numpy, why not as well use pandas?

Comment: @cparks10 Sure but that would be way more painful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSV reader and itertools:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import csv, itertools
# Create a reader
with open('data.txt') as infile:
    rdr = csv.reader(infile)
    # Group the rows by the last column
    data = itertools.groupby(sorted(rdr, key=itemgetter(-1)), key=itemgetter(-1))
# Build a dictionary
dict((key.strip(), [value[:-1] for value in values]) for key,values in data)
#{'FXX': [['.2.', ' .3', ' .5.', ' .2'], ['.5.', ' .3', ' .2 ', ' .9']], 
# 'FCA': [['.3', ' .3', ' .9', ' .3']], 
# 'FAA': [['.5', ' .3', ' .2', ' .1']]}
```

You can do the same with pandas, too:

```
import pandas as pd
# Create a dataframe; note how the regular expression cleanses whitespaces
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header=None, delimiter='\s*,\s*')
# Group rows by the last column
df.groupby(4).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:,:-1].values.tolist()).to_dict()
```

Note that the pandas solution is somewhat shorter.